# Javascript - error with if condition using numbers

Tags: javascript

The program stops working at this line:

if (number1 < 4000000 && number.isInteger(number1/2))
        Here is the program code
        function project2(){
        //alert("testing1,2,3")
         var number1=1
          var number2=2
         var number3
         var solution=0
         var placeholder
     //if( Number.isInteger(23)){
     //  alert("test1 successfull")
     //}
      // if( Number.isInteger(23.1)){
      // alert("test1 unsuccessfull")
     //else{
       //alert("test2 succesfull")
      //}
      //alert("working 1")
          while(number1 && number2 <4000000){
        // alert("working1")
          if (number1<4000000 && number.isInteger(number1/2)){
            solution =solution+number1
       } 
       //alert("working1")
                if (number2<4000000&&number.isInteger(number2/2)){
          solution =solution+number2
         }
            number1=number1+number2
          number2=number1+number2
     }
        alert(solution)
     }
     project2()
What's wrong?

Comment: What "program". I see no program here.

Comment: please watch the uppercase of `Number`: [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code in the question, not the title. You can use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor. Note that you should click Run and see if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: Did you get any error in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 2):

Please watch the upper case of `Number`: [`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

```js
console.log(Number.isInteger(1 / 2));
console.log(Number.isInteger(2 / 2));
```